# Delphi 10.1 Android App. How to pass single byte text as JString.

Tags: android, delphi, unicode

My application print on a Zebra EM220 mobile printer. My national characters are encoded in the code page CP852 (that supports the printer), but Delphi works obviously Unicode.

The printer library has a method for printing text, which passed JString as a text parameter. Unfortunately, use of StringToJString does not work well because there is printed an extra "?" or “t” before each my national characters. It looks like the printer needs a single-byte encoded text, and at two bytes it not knows what to do.

And now the question: How can I encode Unicode string to a single-byte string i CP852 code page and pass this as JString param?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem in Delphi.  And if you have working Java code that handles Unicode text where Delphi does not, please show that code, too.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I encode Unicode string to a single-byte string i CP852 code page and pass this as JString param?

It is possible to convert Unicode data to a particular single-byte charset, using things like Delphi's codepaged AnsiStrings functionality, or the Delphi RTL's `LocaleCharsFromUnicode()` function, or even Java's [`String.getBytes()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.lang.String)) method via JNI.

But you can't pass single-byte data in a `JString` parameter, nor should you be trying to.

`JString` is Delphi's wrapper for [Android's native Java `String` type](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html), which is a UTF-16 encoded string, just like [Delphi's native `UnicodeString` type](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString) is.

If your printer library is really taking `JString` as input then `StringToJString()` will work fine.  It simply copies UTF-16 data as-is from a Delphi `UnicodeString` to a Java `String`.

It is the library's responsibility to convert the Java `String` data from UTF-16 to CP852 (or whatever) when sending data to the actual printer.

If you are having trouble with sending particular characters to the library, that is related to something else, such as sending Unicode characters that don't exist in CP852.  Any trouble you are having with using Unicode text with the library in Delphi should also exist when using Unicode text with the library in Java, since the input is the same either way.